# Making a HTTP POST SOAP request with JSON

Tags: java, android, post, soap, webmethod

I am making a SOAP request to a web method using HTTP Post. The request and response are both JSON.

But while making the POST request i am getting an error :

> The server cannot service the request because the media type is
>   unsupported.

This is my code

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "Method name";
String URL = "service url";
HttpPost httpPost = null;

httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);

HttpEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(requestContent);
httpPost.setEntity(postEntity);
```

I have tried giving Accept-Encoding as application/json , text. But i still get the same error.

Comment: `...It relies on XML Information Set for its message format...` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is an XML-based protocol. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP and the W3C [SOAP Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/).

If you want to communicate using JSON, that's fine - but it isn't SOAP.